# docker container does not start with json unmarshal error

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

Anyone know why I see the following error when I start the container with `--net=host` option? If I remove `--net=host` from the options it starts fine.

```
sudo /usr/bin/docker run -itd --pid=host --net=host --name=contivNet \
  --privileged   -v /etc/openvswitch:/etc/openvswitch \
  -v /etc/kubernetes/ssl:/tmp/kubernets/ssl -v /var/run/:/var/run/ \
  -v /var/contiv:/var/contiv rajenata/contiv:0.1  -m  -p kubernetes \
  -c etcd://127.0.0.1:2379
5c4af0da6e5a2e02748cad9921ed3254f13dc53ed5d4851982be8bf965e38c59
docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 5c4af0da6e5a2e02748cad9921ed3254f13dc53ed5d4851982be8bf965e38c59: [9] System error: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type libcontainer.syncType.
```

Comment: From what little I can see here, I would examine your base image more closely to see what kind of network environment it requires.

Comment: Thanks David. Would it be possible that building the image one version of Docker and then using the image to run on a later version of the docker cause this?

Comment: Doesn't seem likely with the little I know of Docker version history.